# Firestore (Web version 9 modular): getDocsFromCache seems not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firebase and I found [getDocsFromCache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_?authuser=0#getdocsfromcache). I heard that firebase updated it's version to version 9, (modular) and i have to use more than just `query.get({source: "cache"})`. But `getDocsFromCache` didn't work for me. Every time i call `getDocsFromCache`, it does not throw any errors but `snapshot.empty` is always true so i can't access to my documents(collection).

If i have to cache manually, how? If not, what am i missing?

Thank you.

```js
import {
 ​collection,
 ​getDocs,
 ​getDocsFromCache,
 ​query,
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase-config';

export const getReviews = async () => {
 ​const q = query(collection(db, 'review'));

 ​try {
   ​const snapshot = await getDocsFromCache(q);

   ​console.log(snapshot.empty);   // always true but not throwing any error

   ​snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     ​/* ... */
   ​});

 ​} catch (e) {
   // never reach here
   ​const snapshot = await getDocs(q);

   /* ... */
 ​}
};
```

Comment: `getDocsFromCache` being empty is not an error condition when what's in the cache says that your query has no results. If at any point in the past, when the last time you called `getDocs(q)` returned no results, the cache will have stored the same response - no results. You can either purge your cache to try again or simply throw your own error when you get no results when you were expecting some.

Comment: Yes I tried `getDocsFromCache` right after I successfully got some results with `getDocs`, but It was always returning empty response... Thanks for your very helpful comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation on [configuring offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence):

> For the web, offline persistence is disabled by default. To enable persistence, call the `enablePersistence` method.

So make sure to enable the cache by calling this right after [initializing Firebase and Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize):

```
import { enableIndexedDbPersistence } from "firebase/firestore"; 

enableIndexedDbPersistence(db);
```

Comment: Oh, yes I tried `enableIndexedDbPersistence(db)` before but it didn't work for me... but thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`enableIndexedDbPersistence` is deprecated (at least in firebase v9). Consider using the following approach (I took it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)):

```js
import { initializeFirestore, memoryLocalCache } from "firebase/firestore";

initializeFirestore(app, {
  localCache: memoryLocalCache(),
});
```

you may also import and use `persistentLocalCache` instead of `memoryLocalCache` if you like.

Comment: persistentLocalCache solved my issue +1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, This [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) resolved my problem. you can try this one as a example.

```
    const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  localCache: persistentLocalCache({
    cacheSizeBytes: 200000000,
    useFetchStreams: true,
    tabManager: persistentMultipleTabManager(),
  }),
});
```